# How to assign different row‘s rank value to new column?

Tags: python, r

for example, I have two columns of data(person,class_score), different persons have different classes and different scores, how to create new columns of classes, and assign the score to the correct place? because there are plenty of classes and I am trying to find a smart way to do that

```
person class_score
Joe gram(-),phy(+),bio(++)
Ray chem(+),bio(-)
Jenny fin(++),db(-),pre(-)
```

trying to convert to this way

```
person cls_sco gram phy bio chem fin db pre
Joe ..........  -   +   ++  NA   NA  NA NA
Ray ........... NA  NA  -   +   NA  NA NA
Jenny ......... NA  NA  NA  NA  ++  -  -
```

Example of data structure and output:

[image]

Comment: [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) can be a good place to start if you've not tried to this sort of thing before!  please include any code you've tried, also the actual data format & structure of the input file - that screen shot suggests that it's a plain text file but might be something else.   also, don't include textual data as images, paste the actual text into the question formatted as a "code sample"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option

**Code**

```
import re
import pandas as pd

from itertools import chain

def make_table(data):
  " Creates nested list of list (i.e. table) from score data "
  # subjects in alphabetical order
  cols = sorted(set(chain(*map(lambda x: x[0], data.values()))))

  yield ['person', 'cls_sco'] + list(cols)

  for person, values in data.items():
    subjects = values[0]
    scores = values[1]
    column = []
    for subject in cols:
      try:
        index = subjects.index(subject)
        column.append(scores[index])
      except ValueError:
        # person doesn't have this subject
        column.append('NA')

    yield [person, '....'] + column

# Parse subjects and scores from CSV file
with open('data.csv') as f:
  data = {}
  re_subject = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\(') # detect subject in string
  re_score = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')  # detects in string

  next(f) # skip header row
  for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)

    # Parse out subject and scores from each line
    current_subjects = [re_subject.search(x).group(1) for x in line[1].split(',')]
    current_scores = [re_score.search(x).group(1) for x in line[1].split(',')]

    data[line[0]] = (current_subjects, current_scores)

# Table of scores (nested list)
table = list(make_table(data))

# Convert to Pandas dataframe for display as table
df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:],columns=table[0]).set_index('person')
print(df)
```

**Test**

```
Input File: data.csv

person class_score
Joe gram(-),phy(+),bio(++)
Ray chem(+),bio(-)
Jenny fin(++),db(-),pre(-)
```

*Output*

```
      cls_sco bio chem  db fin gram phy pre
person                                      
Joe       ....  ++   NA  NA  NA    -   +  NA
Ray       ....   -    +  NA  NA   NA  NA  NA
Jenny     ....  NA   NA   -  ++   NA  NA   -
```